# Prove or disprove: If $B - A$ is nonempty, then $\overline{\overline{A}} < \overline{\overline{A \cup B}}$

Tags: proof-writing, proof-verification

Prove or disprove: If $B - A$ is nonempty, then $\overline{\overline{A}} < \overline{\overline{A \cup B}}$

Disprove (backwards proof): If  $\overline{\overline{A}} < \overline{\overline{A \cup B}}$, then $\overline{\overline{A}}$ $\leq$ $\overline{\overline {A \cup B}}$, but $\overline{\overline{A}} \neq \overline{\overline {A \cup B}}$. This implies that $\overline{\overline{B}} > \overline{\overline{A}}$ and $B-A$ is nonempty.

Is this proof valid? Should I add more to make it more clear?

Comment: Are these finite sets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. $\overline{\overline A}\lt\overline{\overline{A\cup B}}$ does **not** imply $\overline{\overline B}\gt\overline{\overline A}$; consider the example $A=\{1,2\},B=\{3\}$.
2. $\overline{\overline A}\lt\overline{\overline{A\cup B}}$ **does** imply (trivially) that $B-A$ is nonempty, but that's **not** the same as saying that "$B-A$ is nonempty" implies $\overline{\overline A}\lt\overline{\overline{A\cup B}}$. $\ \ P\Rightarrow Q$ is one thing, $Q\Rightarrow P$ is another thing.
3. Are you talking about finite sets or arbitrary sets? The statement you have to prove or disprove is always true if $A$ is finite, but it's not necessarily true if $A$ is infinite. For instance, if $A=\{1,2,3,\dots\}$ and $B=\{0\}$, then $B-A$ is nonempty, but $\overline{\overline A}=\overline{\overline{A\cup B}}$